# Quick Algorithmic Complexity calculation

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I'm familiar with Big O stuff and generally know how to use the critical section to figure out the complexity. This one was giving me the works a bit so I'd love an answer and a small explanation:

```
i = 1;
while(i<= n){
   if(i%2 == 0)(
   System.out.println(i);
   }
   i++;
}
```

From what I understand, the body of the if will run n/2 times because only the even i's would print out. So would the overall complexity be:
1+ (n/2) making the Big O  O(n)?`

Comment: Actually, this is an infinite loop if `i <= n`. I think you forgot something there

Comment: Oops. Forgot to increment i in the loop! @dasblinkenlight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overall complexity is n + n/2 *(the complexity of `System.out.println(i);`). In this case I think you can assume the complexity of the call to `System.out.println` is constant, thus the overall complexity is O(N). Still important to notice is that you can not ignore the complexity of the iteration.

Comment: Thank you. That was a pretty clear answer. So the iteration is the thing that runs n times while the body of the if runs n/2 times. The initial i declaration is just constant which would mean the overall function would be 1+ n + n/2. Correct?

Comment: @samz_manu correct. Still to be more precise note that you are executing n/2 times the function System.out.println in theory this can be a complex and expensive operation - for instance if you are printing out a tree or some other complex structure

Comment: Got it. One more thing that still kind of confuses me. Is the argument of the if irrelevant to the complexity? There's no cost to checking if its equal or not is there? Really the complexity comes from the code executed within it and not from checking of the argument.

Comment: It is important - you are performing two operations there - a modulo calculation and an equality comparison. In theory both operations can be complex for some different type.

Comment: So why didn't we include that in our function? 1 + n + (complexity of operations) + n/2 would then be the one we should be considering right?

Comment: In fact the correct way to write all this is `1 + n * (modulo_complexity + equality_check_complexity) + n/2 * (System.out.println complexity)`. I skipped the comparison as in this case it is obviously constant but your note is correct - it will not always be neglectible

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for detailed explanations. Accepted as solution

Answer (score 0):

The overall complexity is still O(n), because checking the value of `i%2` and incrementing `i` it still counts as work. The body of the `if` statement that that executes `n/2` times just adds an additional O(n) amount of work.

Answer (score 0):

You have misinterpreted what exactly the *body* of your code (rather the body of your loop) is. This is the body of your code(/loop):

```
if (i%2 == 0) {
   System.out.println(i);
}
i++;
```

And this body will be executed total *n* times even though half of the time the `if` condition would fail.